# TortoiseSVN commit is taking so long that connection to remote end is getting closed down

Tags: svn, commit

For a project at uni we have to work on an existing project with about 13000 files. We need to do an initial commit to our svn repo, however the transfer rate in TortoiseSVN is so slow that the connection to our remote end gets closed down every time I try to commit. Usually the rate is around 50 kBytes/second and the project's size is about 100MB

Any ideas how I could speed it up? Or is there a better way to go at this entirely?

EDIT: We are not allowed to use Git or anything else aside from SVN

Comment: What's your server/client version? What's the bandwidth?

Comment: My version is 1.11.1 and my upload bandwidth is 1-2 Mbytes/s

I have no idea about the server. We don't get any information like that

Comment: I expect that your SVN server version is very old. Your admins should plan an upgrade to SVN 1.10.x release (or the next LTS release when will be released). If there is any firewall / proxy or other intermediate service - its worth checking it as well.